# Use and meaning of the word [綻]{ほころ}ばす

Tags: verbs, song-lyrics, transitivity

Found this word in this context (a song)

> 生ぬるい惰性で生活を**綻ばす**
>
> ゴミ箱みたいな部屋のなかで、時が
>
> 過ぎるのをただただ待ってる　それだけ
>
> 眠れない夜更けに呼吸の音を聞く

To me, it looks like this line says "with halfhearted momentum, (I) tear through life"; but this seems strange.

**What is the meaning of "seikatsu wo hokorobasu" and the phrase before it?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[綻ばす](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/203741/meaning/m0u/) is [shorter alternative](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/28522/7810) to 綻ばせる, the causative form of [綻ぶ](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/203745/meaning/m0u/) (yet is an alternative form of [綻びる](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/203744/meaning/m0u/)).

In this context, 綻ぶ is used synonymously with [破綻する](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/176773/meaning/m0u/%E7%A0%B4%E7%B6%BB/) "split at the seams; break down; fall apart", so the overall meaning of the line would be:

> Wrecking (my) life with halfhearted/lukewarm force of habit...